# CiviRules: Is there a trigger that can be used if a groupcontact is deleted?

Tags: civirules

The trigger "Contact is removed from Group" doesn't fire if the groupcontact is deleted (and not removed). Is there a trigger, that can be used to react on the deletion of a groupcontact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not in the list it does not exist yet :-). As long as the pre hook is used in the group delete it should not be hard to add. Are you in a position to check this and add it?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
I just tested the hooks hook_civicrm_pre and hook_civicrm_post. Are those the hooks you mean? Interesting is, that both of them show the same results if a group_contact is removed and a group_contact is deleted. So if the CiviRule trigger would depend on those hooks, I would expect, that the trigger would react on both events. But it only reacts on remove and not on delete.

Comment: You would have to check in the Civirules extension to see what happens there. You can start in the civirules.php on the pre (because that is where something should happen on delete) and follow from there?